# CocoaPods/Podspec and *.framework

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios-frameworks, cocoapods

CocoaPods question:

I have created a framework bundled with a static library inside, depending on AFNetworking and a resource bundle (based on those two tutorials to create FWKs http://www.blackjaguarstudios.com/blog/programming/2012/11/22/xcode-45-creating-ios-framework-and-hold-my-hand-im-3-years-old and https://github.com/bclubb/iOS-Framework)

I'd love to create a podspec so that people just add a line in their Podfile, which would, on pod install, add my framework and the AFNetworking, if needed.

Is this possible?

Comment: Anything is possible. ;)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I have actually done this a lot at my office. We have tons of private source code that is re-used quite a bit. CocoaPods has helped get new projects started much quicker and makes them a whole lot easier to update.

While it is possible to add your framework to the podspec, I have found it much easier to just pass the static library and headers over via CocoaPods rather than worry about the framework.

You will have to update your podspec based on your project, but here are the important parts:

```
s.source_files = 'StaticLib/Headers/*.h'
s.preserve_paths = 'StaticLib/libYourLibrary.a'
s.library = 'YourLibrary'
s.xcconfig = { 'LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS' => '$(PODS_ROOT)/ProjectFolder/LibraryFolder' }    

s.dependency = 'AFNetworking'
```

This will copy your static library over as well as bring over AFNetworking with your pod too. This will make your static lib much smaller (not having to build it in) and speed up how quickly the user can import your pod.

If you must use framework, the same stuff from above still applies, but you might have some slight tweaking to do. All a framework is is a pretty folder structure for a static lib and headers anyway, so why bother with the extra stuff. The source is all still built into the lPods.a static lib anyway. Hope this helps you out.

Comment: Thanks, just knowing that it is will push me to investigate further =)

Comment: I tried with this repo : https://github.com/BugsterIO/BugsterIO-iOS and the following line in the podfile : pod 'BugsterIO', :podspec => "https://raw.github.com/BugsterIO/BugsterIO-iOS/0.8/BugsterIO.podspec"
. But it's not working. Any idea?

Comment: The error is : Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Bugster", referenced from:

Comment: Looks like your static lib/framework doesn't support i386(simulator). Add that in and rebuild/update. Used to see that a lot, one of the drawbacks of static libs. Also, if you are going static lib route, make sure you are using a build script to create a universal build. Xcode 4 doesn't do it for you anymore.

Comment: There is a downside to this approach, that you no longer get the syntax for framework inclusion of header files (#import <MyFramework.h>.  For public frameworks it means two sets of instructions on how to set up a project to make use of your framework.

Answer (score 1):

In fact you can create your own libxxx.a or xxxx.framework with Cocoapods now. Cocoapods will take care the details such as universal binary and public headers. Pls Check: https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/using-pod-lib-create.html and http://blog.cocoapods.org/Pod-Authors-Guide-to-CocoaPods-Frameworks/