# Create podspec with static library

Tags: ios, podspec

I try to create my own podspec embedded with static library, and I found this similar post [CocoaPod/Podspec and *.framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14102703/cocoapod-podspec-and-framework). However I still get fail while Validating spec.

1. My project structure

[image]

2. My podspec
   [image]
3. error message

   - ERROR | [iOS] Returned an unsuccessful exit code. You can use `--verbose` for more information.

     - WARN  |  TunnelFramework/TunnelFramework/Client/TunnelClient.m:482:2: warning: 設定成 80 port 非8080 [-W#warnings]
     - WARN  |  TunnelFramework/TunnelFramework/Client/TunnelClient.m:121:22: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'unsigned long *' to parameter of type 'unsigned int *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     - NOTE  |  Headers/Private/TunnelFramework/IOTCAPIs.h:429:48: note: passing argument to parameter 'pnVersion' here
     - NOTE  |  ld: warning: directory not found for option '-LTunnelFramework/Tunnel/Lib'
     - NOTE  |  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Is there any hint to make right podspec with static library ??

Comment: can you copy-paste the error message instead of image (hard to read)